# PM2 Keyboardinterrupt

Tags: logging, pm2

When I do pm2 logs followed by the process name, such as pm2 logs testing, the logs display as expected. However, the only way I can exit the logs is by using ctrl + c. This action triggers a keyboardinterrupt error, disrupting the process completely.

Despite attempting various solutions, such as code modifications and restarting or reloading the process (pm2 restart testing for example), the error persists and remains unresolved. I can't find any guides on this issue either.